# Spider Runs using scrapy but there is no data stored into a csv

Tags: scrapy

I have written a code that passes through links within a web page to extract data and move to the next page.  It is the about link from each author in quotes.toscrape.com.

```
  import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com',]

    def parse(self, response):
        linkto = response.css('div.quote > span > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for links in linkto:
            links = response.urljoin(links)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=links, callback = scrapy.parse_about)


        nextp = response.css('li.next > a::attr(href)').extract()
        if nextp:
            nextp = response.urljoin(nextp)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nextp, callback=self.parse)



    def parse_about(self, response):
        yield {
            'date_of_birth': response.css('span.author-born-date::text').extract(),
            'author': response.css('h3.author-title::text').extract(),
        }
```

I executed in the command prompt:

```
scrapy crawl test -o test.csv
```

but the results I got:

```
019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: quotestoscrape)
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.1.1.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 17.5.0, Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 13 2018, 17:33:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018), cryptography 2.5, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'quotestoscrape.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['quotestoscrape.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'quotestoscrape'}
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-03-20 16:36:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com> (referer: None)
2019-03-20 16:36:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\kenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\kenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\kenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\kenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\kenny\quotestoscrape\quotestoscrape\spiders\QuoteTestSpider.py", line 13, in parse
    yield scrapy.Request(url=links, callback = scrapy.parse_about)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse_about'
2019-03-20 16:36:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-03-20 16:36:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 446,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2701,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 20, 21, 36, 4, 41000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 20, 21, 36, 3, 468000)}
2019-03-20 16:36:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And my csv file I moved it to is empty:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpU5G.png)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

According to your log method `parse_about` is not called because you are trying to call `scrapy.parse_about` instead of spider's `self.parse_about`:

```
....
        for links in linkto:
            links = response.urljoin(links)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=links, callback = self.parse_about)
```

As your application doesn't scrape any data -> It creates empty csv file as result.